# Question on polynomials from Ferrar's Higher Algebra for Schools

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling on this for some time now but have been unable to solve. Question is as follows:

Prove that there are two values of $h$ for which $$2x^2 - 3y^2 + 4z^2 + yz + 6zx - hxy$$

is the product of linear factors, and find these factors.

I began with the following deduction:

As this is a homogeneous quadratic of three variables, then it must have only two linear factors. I therefore equated
$$2x^2 - 3y^2 + 4z^2 + yz + 6zx - hxy = (ax + by + cz)(dx + ey + fz)$$

and, after expanding RHS and equating coefficients, obtained the following:

$$x^2: ad = 2$$ $$y^2: be = -3$$  $$z^2: cf = 4$$ $$yz: bf + ce = 1$$
$$zx: af + cd =6$$ $$xy: ae + bd = -h$$

This then lead me to some quadratics but I have been unable to find explicit values for $a, b, c, d, e, f$ and I have been unable to find two values for h. The closest I came was when I substituted in the equation for $xy$ and obtained $$(ae)^2 + hae - 6 = 0$$.

I knew from this that $h$ was the sum of two numbers whose product was $-6$ but I was no closer to finding these numbers. The other two quadratics I found from substituting into equations from $yz$ and $xy$ both factorised, but none gave explicit values for $a, b, c, d, e, f$.

I don't know if I'm approaching this in the correct way but equating coefficients has been mentioned in this chapter.

Solutions given are: $$(x + y + z)(2x - 3y + 4z)$$

and $$(\frac{1}{2}x + y + z)(4x - 3y + 4z)$$

As stated, I have know idea how to derive this result so any help would be gratefully received.

A previous question is similar but the interesting hint gives a different method which I cannot get to work in this question. I give it now for reference in the hope that this method works in this case.

Prove that there are two values of $f$ for which

$$2x^2 - 5xy - 3y^2 - x + 2fy - 3$$

is a product of two linear factors. State the two values of $f$.

HINT. $2x^2 - 5xy - 3y^2 \equiv (2x + y)(x - 3y)$, so that the two linear factors must be $(2x + y + p)(x - 3y - \frac{3}{p})$.

Solutions are $5$ and $-\frac{15}{4}$.

I'm probably looking too deeply into this, and the answer is hiding in plain sight. Nevertheless, this does seem more than a little tricky to me.

Many thanks in advance once again for any advice given.

Comment: Only parabolas. For equal roots of quadratic, discriminant = 0 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further hint: Divide throughout by $x^2$ and set $ A = \frac{y}{x}, B = \frac{z}{x}$.
This reduces to a variant of the previous problem.

Note: We divide by $x^2$ to make the $hxy$ and the $2fy$ line up, and so it's clear that it's a variant.
We could also divide by $y^2$ or $z^2$, but that would less clearly be a variant.

---

More generally, the [discriminant of a conic](https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant/) section tells you what shape it has, which will lead to a "two-step" solution.  (This is not quite the discriminant of the quadratic.) If you're studying this is school, my guess is that they will next talk about this.